# php watermark and save image

Tags: php

I am trying to add a watermark to an image and then save the image to another file with php. This is the code that I have so far, but for some reason the watermark is not appearing on the image in the new directory. 
The original image is saved in the path `$old_path` and I want to save it to `$new_path` after applying the watermark.

```
    $old_path = "images_upload/".$name.".".$type;
    $new_path = "images_main/".$name.".".$type;
    ////////////////////water mark
$main_image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($old_path));

// Load the logo image
$logoImage = imagecreatefrompng("assets/watermark.png");
imagealphablending($logoImage, true);

// Get dimensions
$imageWidth=imagesx($main_image);
$imageHeight=imagesy($main_image);

$logoWidth=imagesx($logoImage);
$logoHeight=imagesy($logoImage); 

// Paste the logo
imagecopy(
   // source
   $main_image,
   // destination
   $logoImage,
   // destination x and y
   $imageWidth-$logoWidth, $imageHeight-$logoHeight,
   // source x and y
   0, 0,
   // width and height of the area of the source to copy
   $logoWidth, $logoHeight);
    ////////////////////////

    rename($old_path, $new_path);// save image
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never write down the `imagecopy` result to any file, you just rename the old image to the new path - use [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) instead:

```
 imagejpeg($logoImage, $new_path);
```

Comment: I don't want to echo out the image to the browser. I want to copy it from $old_path to $new_path after applying the watermark. (so the new image in $new_path will have the watermark on it)

Comment: I tested this function doesn't accept an argument for a new file path.  What should be done now to generate a new image file?

Comment: @gadget00 of course it does, see linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't outputting the image anywhere.  You need to output it.  All you're doing right now is renaming your old file to the new.

Try `imagepng()` or equivalent for your format.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: I am using the rename function to copy the image.

Comment: @user1481850, I don't think you understand.  When you use `imagecopy`, the operations only happen in memory.  They are not saved to a file until you choose to do so.  Read the documentation I pointed you to.